# Apply jQuery to elements created by ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to apply jQuery methods, functions etc for elements that have been created with ajax.
In my page there is a dropdown list #cat_id and depending on the selection made, a set of UL elements are created. I then need to call the following function for each element created:

```
$('#allowSpacesTagsX').tagit({ itemName: 'itemX', fieldName: 'tagsX', availableTags: sampleTagsX, allowSpaces: true });
```

where allowSpacesTagsX (X=1,2,3,....) is the id of the created UL elements. This method binds the UL to an auto-complete tagging widget similar to the tagging element used in StackOverflow.

Normally the code above would be included in the document.ready for the static elements but I need to add it for each element created with ajax.

This is a small sample of code to understand my question better:

```
<script src="../js/tag-it.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cat_id').live('change', function(e){
           $.post('../includes/ajax.php', {   
            cat_id : $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value')}, function(data) {
            $("#tagholder").html(data);
           });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

### Edit:

example added to demonstrate an example of the code that should be produced:

```
$(function(){ // Creates the arrays of tags to be assigned to each tag field
var sampleTags1 = ['USB', 'DVB', 'GSM', 'OEM'];
var sampleTags2 = ['Alfa Romeo', 'Audi', 'Chevrolet', 'Mazda', 'Mercedes'];
var sampleTags3 = ['20cm', '21cm', '8in'];
$('#allowSpacesTags1').tagit({ itemName: 'item1', fieldName: 'tags1', availableTags: sampleTags1, allowSpaces: true });
$('#allowSpacesTags2').tagit({ itemName: 'item2', fieldName: 'tags2', availableTags: sampleTags2, allowSpaces: true });
$('#allowSpacesTags3').tagit({ itemName: 'item3', fieldName: 'tags3', availableTags: sampleTags3, allowSpaces: true });
});
```

Comment: Put it in the ajax success callback

Comment: I tried that, obviously I'm not doing it right though. Can you please tell me how to do it properly?

Comment: `function (data) { $("#tagholder").html(data); $("#allowSpacesTagsX").tagit({....}); }`

Comment: Ok, got it. But theres a small problem here. $("#allowSpacesTagsX").tagit({....}); } needs to be repeated for each element that is returned, meaning if ajax returns 3 ULs then I also need the code repeated for each UL with X replaced with the UL's id.

Comment: Then use a selector that only evaluates the beginning of each id: `$("ul[id^='allowSpacestags']")`

Comment: I've updated my question with more sample code so you can see an example of the code if it where to be static. The point I wish to make is the different sets of tags and the jQuery calls.

Comment: can you please accept the answer if that has solved your problems? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="../js/tag-it.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cat_id').live('change', function(e){
       $.post('../includes/ajax.php', {   
        cat_id : $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value')},
        function(data) {
        $("#tagholder").html(data);//places your ajax content
        //grab that element again and then apply any jquery function to it
        //example add a class to an arbitary h1 tag inside #tagholder
        $("#tagholder h1").css('class','heading');//like so
       });
    }); 
});
</script>
```